# is log_in(user) the same as log_in user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Doing Hartl's Rails tutorial, [chapter 8.2.1](https://www.learnenough.com/course/ruby_on_rails_tutorial_4th_edition/basic_login/logging_in/a_working_log_in_method).

We define:

```
def log_in(user)
   session[:user_id] = user_id
end
```

And then we invoke the `log_in` method in the controller:

```
def create
   user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
   if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
     log_in user
     redirect_to user
   else
     flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
     render 'new'
   end
 end
```

Why we write `log_in user` instead of `log_in(user)` in the controller? Are they equivalent syntaxes? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

As a part of ruby's syntactic sugar, you can drop the parentheses on method calls

For example lets say you have a method that takes in a hash

You can call it any of these ways:

```
method_name({param1: 1, param2: 2})
method_name(param1: 1, param2: 2)
method_name param1: 1, param2: 2
```

When do use which? Depends.

If you want to nest method calls, its best to be verbose. If you need to pass multiple hashes, then you need to tell ruby their boundaries, by using the `{}` brackets.